# Terraform statefile per module approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In my efforts to learn terraform a build this sample environment with it.
I am using modules and input / output variables to connect them.

The root module is the one containing the following `main.tf`

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}

module "vpc" {
  source          = "./vpc"
  vpc_cidr        = var.vpc_cidr
  app_name        = var.app_name
  app_environment = var.app_environment
}

module "networking" {
  source             = "./networking"
  app_name           = var.app_name
  app_environment    = var.app_environment
  private_subnets    = var.private_subnets
  public_subnets     = var.public_subnets
  availability_zones = var.availability_zones
  internal_domain    = var.internal_domain
  # from modules
  vpc_id             = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

module "iam" {
  source          = "./iam"
  app_name        = var.app_name
  app_environment = var.app_environment
}

module "cluster" {
  source          = "./cluster"
  app_name        = var.app_name
  app_environment = var.app_environment
}

module "security" {
  source   = "./security"
  vpc_cidr = var.vpc_cidr
  # from modules
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id
}


...

module "mysql" {
  source               = "./mysql"
  app_name             = var.mysql_app_name
  repo                 = var.mysql_repo
  port                 = var.mysql_port
  protocol             = var.mysql_protocol
  app_count            = var.mysql_app_count
  aws_region           = var.aws_region
  # from modules
  vpc_id               = module.vpc.vpc_id
  iam_role_arn         = module.iam.iam_role_arn
  dns_zone_id          = module.networking.dns_zone_id
  private_networks_ids = module.networking.private_networks_ids
  cluster_id           = module.cluster.cluster_id
  security_group_id    = module.security.internal_security_group_id
}

module "stockapp_example" {
  source                            = "./stockapp"
  app_name                          = var.stockapp_app_name
  repo                              = var.stockapp_repo
  port                              = var.stockapp_port
  protocol                          = var.stockapp_protocol
  app_protocol                      = var.stockapp_app_protocol
  app_protocol_for_target_group     = var.stockapp_app_protocol_for_target_group
  finhub_dns_name                   = "${var.finhub_app_protocol}://${var.finhub_app_name}.${var.internal_domain}:${var.finhub_port}/${var.finhub_app_name}"
  mysql_dns_name                    = "${var.mysql_protocol_for_dns}://${var.mysql_app_name}.${var.internal_domain}/${var.mysql_schema}"
  app_count                         = var.stockapp_app_count
  aws_region                        = var.aws_region
  # from modules
  vpc_id                            = module.vpc.vpc_id
  iam_role_arn                      = module.iam.iam_role_arn
  dns_zone_id                       = module.networking.dns_zone_id
  private_networks_ids              = module.networking.private_networks_ids
  public_networks_ids               = module.networking.public_networks_ids
  cluster_id                        = module.cluster.cluster_id
  security_group_id                 = module.security.internal_security_group_id
  security_group_id_for_load_balancer = module.security.external_security_group_id
}
```

I am using one single global state, I know is possible to use one state per module, but I am unsure what that entails.

Won't this approach get the way of the input / output logical connections among modules ?

Can you help me understand how using with state per module approach work ?

EDIT:
[Here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/) for example is mentioned

> There is one module to deploy a frontend-app, another to deploy a backend-app, another for the MySQL database, and so on. To deploy such an environment, you’d have to manually run terraform apply in each of the subfolder, wait for it to complete, and then run terraform apply

Also [here](https://terraspace.cloud/docs/state/approaches/)

> A statefile per module
> The finest-grain approach is to have a statefile per module. So instead of deploying stacks, which groups related modules together, we choose to deploy each module individually.

Comment: "I know is possible to use one state per module, but I am unsure what that entails." No it's not. That's not how Terraform modules work. The way you are doing it is the only way. If you found some documentation that lead you to believe that, please link to it.

Comment: That's not really terraform "modules", it's just a bunch of independent terraform "root" modules that you can run together using Terragrunt. That is a non-standard way of using Terraform.

Comment: Alright, thanks @MarB, feel free to formulate an answer :)